# How to seperate APC cache for different URLs in case of shared hosting?

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, apc

I am using APC cache with doctrine2 on shared hosting.

I have hosted several instances of same project but the versions are different. So I do not want that they share the same cache.

For example I have following hosting URLs:

```
http://phpdemo.******.com:9040/ilook/qa
http://phpdemo.******.com:9040/ilook/android
http://phpdemo.******.com:9040/ilook/dev
http://phpdemo.******.com:9040/ilook/client
```

> Is there any way to differentiate the cache for them?

php.ini settings:

```
[APC]
apc.shm_size = '128M'
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.num_files_hint=0
apc.user_entries_hint=0
apc.ttl=0
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.stat=1
apc.enable_cli=0
apc.file_update_protection=2
apc.max_file_size=2M
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.use_request_time=1
apc.slam_defense=0
apc.stat_ctime=0
apc.canonicalize=1
apc.write_lock=1
apc.report_autofilter=0
apc.rfc1867=0
apc.rfc1867_prefix =upload_
apc.rfc1867_name=APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_freq=0
apc.rfc1867_ttl=3600
apc.lazy_classes=0
apc.lazy_functions=0
```

As I am using ZF1 + Doctrine2, so below are the configuration lines I have used in bootstrap.php file.

```
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;

$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setResultCacheImpl($cache);
```

Comment: You should try to prefix the cache by the name of the project, ie qa, android, dev or client. Are you using Doctrine2 with a Framework? If yes which one?

Comment: Yes I am using doctrine2 with zend framework1. I have added configuration for APC cache in bootstrap.php file in my question.

Comment: Did you try to define a custom namespace related to the project? Following what's inside your bootstrap.php, `$cache->setNamespace('project_name');` ([see](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php#L36-L61))

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your `bootstrap.php`, you should be able to define a different namespace to your cache per project, like:

```
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;

// define the cache for this project only
$cache->setNamespace('project_name');

$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setResultCacheImpl($cache);
```